How to join smoothly body part of my character without creating too many vertices for animation?
I'm trying to merge and smooth body parts of my character together without creating 200.000+ vertices each time. I've tried so far:

Using Remesh + scuplting with a smooth: but it creates loads of vertices.
Deleting some vertices of both body parts and manually joining them together using merging or add new vertices but it's kinda breaking my mesh and takes a lot of time

I don't understand how to have a good quality result without ending with a +2.000.000 vertices character. Could you enlighten me? (I'd like to animate my character on Mixamo)
Thanks a lot for you help!


Hello, what is your goal exactly? If you plan to create a character in order to animate it, use a low-poly mesh so that you don't have this sort of problem. If you plan to create a character to sculpt it, use the Boolean modifier or tool to merge the vertices

I'd like to created a character to animate it. But I'd like it to be kinda good quality to sculpt it. Isn't it possible?

If you want to animate a character it needs to be low-poly, you can still sculpt a high-poly version but at the end you'll need to retopologize a low-poly version and bake the details onto the low-poly. If you are a beginner, maybe forget sculpting for the moment and focus on modeling a low-poly character?

Thanks for the tip! I'll try to find ways to stylize as much as possible in low poly and then use Mixamo to animate to start. Thx
